# focus() and select() didn't work to gather on key-down function and it works on mouse focus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What i have done is:
I have some input types and I done key-down to shift focus on each input by giving class input_index_1 to input_index_etc.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", ".inputbox", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38) {
    var classNames = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    for (var contarray = 0, l = classNames.length; contarray < l; contarray++) {
      var current_iterating_class = classNames[contarray];
      if (current_iterating_class.indexOf("input_index_") != -1) {
        var current_class = current_iterating_class;
      }
    }
    var pos = current_class.substr(current_class.indexOf("_") + 7);
    pos = Number(pos);
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { //downarrow(forw)                        
      pos += 1;
      console.log("pos+1=" + pos);
      if (this.tagName == "SELECT") {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      $(".input_index_" + pos).focus().select();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { //uparrow(prev)
      pos -= 1;
      if (this.tagName == "SELECT") {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      $(".input_index_" + pos).focus().select();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label" for="sname">name</label>
<input type="text" id="sname" class="form-control inputbox input_index_1" name="sname" value="name">
<label class="control-label" for="work">work</label>
<input type="text" id="work" class="form-control inputbox input_index_2" name="work" value="work">
<label class="control-label" for="salary">salary</label>
<input type="text" id="salary" class="form-control inputbox input_index_3" name="sal" value="1234">
```

the focus works properly but didn't work select().

Comment: Off topic: you might be interested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex as you seem to be re-inventing the wheel

Comment: Is there a reason you don't like using tab and shift-tab to go between controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery [$().select()](https://api.jquery.com/select/#select) function is not the same as the javascript [node.select()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) method.

Your `.focus().select()` can be changed to:

```
 $(".input_index_" + pos).focus();
 if ($(".input_index_" + pos).length) 
      setTimeout(() => $(".input_index_" + pos)[0].select(), 10)
```

couple of notes why it's not just `.focus()[0].select()`

- you're not checking if element exists so pressing up on first element would give an error
- the .focus() DOM action occurs after your code has run and resets the selection, so you need to give it a bit of time to handle this.  There are other ways, such as catching `focus` event, but this is possibly closest to your original code

```js
$(document).on("keydown", ".inputbox", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38) {
    var classNames = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    for (var contarray = 0, l = classNames.length; contarray < l; contarray++) {
      var current_iterating_class = classNames[contarray];
      if (current_iterating_class.indexOf("input_index_") != -1) {
        var current_class = current_iterating_class;
      }
    }
    var pos = current_class.substr(current_class.indexOf("_") + 7);
    pos = Number(pos);
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { //downarrow(forw)                        
      pos += 1;
      console.log("pos+1=" + pos);
      if (this.tagName == "SELECT") {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      $(".input_index_" + pos).focus()
      if ($(".input_index_" + pos).length) 
          setTimeout(() => $(".input_index_" + pos)[0].select(), 10)
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { //uparrow(prev)
      pos -= 1;
      if (this.tagName == "SELECT") {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      $(".input_index_" + pos).focus();
      if ($(".input_index_" + pos).length) 
          setTimeout(() => $(".input_index_" + pos)[0].select(), 10)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label" for="sname">name</label>
<input type="text" id="sname" class="form-control inputbox input_index_1" name="sname" value="name">
<label class="control-label" for="work">work</label>
<input type="text" id="work" class="form-control inputbox input_index_2" name="work" value="work">
<label class="control-label" for="salary">salary</label>
<input type="text" id="salary" class="form-control inputbox input_index_3" name="sal" value="1234">
```